# how is indirection operator returns pointer adress with operator overloading

Tags: c++

I want to understand below code:

```
class EdgeIterator {

  EdgeIterator() {}

  EdgeIterator(const EdgeList edges) {}

  EdgeIterator begin() { return *this; }


  EdgeIterator& operator*() { return *this; }

}
```

in the `begin` function how `return *this` returns and `EdgeIterator`
 and, in the  `operator*` function how is it returns `EdgeIterator&`.

Comment: taken from this code https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/blob/master/src/mcts/node.h#L418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`begin()` returns by value, so it returns a copy of `*this`.

`operator*()` returns by reference, so it returns a reference to `*this`.

Here's similar code for better explanation:

```
struct X
{
  std::string a;
  X copy() { return *this; }
  X& ref() { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
  X x{"Hi"};
  x.copy().a = "Bye";
  std::cout << x.a << '\n'; // prints Hi
  x.ref().a = "Bye";
  std::cout << x.a << '\n'; // prints Bye
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f30bcaf80b95eedd)

Comment: Isn't * used for dereferencing a pointer, `this` is not a pointer.

Comment: @eguneys But `this` *is* a pointer; a pointer to the object on which the member function is invoked.